# Efecto abrir y Cerrar con JQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Buen Día.

ando trabajando un ejercicio con Jquery y requiero crear un efecto donde al oprimir una carpeta se abra y se cierre con el click.

Lo logro usando en Jquery el siguiente código:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.img-open').hide();
});

$('.card').on('click', function() {
    $('.img-open').show();
    $('.img-close').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUR0Y.png" alt="" class="img-close">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv4z.png" alt="" class="img-open">
    <span>Gerencia</span>
</div>
```

Creo el efecto con dos Imagenes de la Carpeta una cerrada y una abierta, de esta forma hago la simulación cambiando una imagen por la otra.

Como puedo hacer que se abra y cierra como si fuera un efecto `.toogle` de jquery

Agradesco cualquier aporte.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si deseas utilizar el `toogle` una manera sencilla en que puedes hacerlo es de la siguiente manera:

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.img-open').hide();
});

$('.card').on('click', function() {
    $(this).find('img').toggle();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUR0Y.png" alt="" class="img-close">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv4z.png" alt="" class="img-open">
    <span>Gerencia</span>
</div>
```

Aquí te dejo la documentación por si la necesitas: [.toogle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Espero te ayude, saludos.

Comment: Hola #Blas David, buen ejemplo! deseo el mismo efecto pero en una fila de una tabla   , resulta que cuando se hace el toogle se cambian todas las filas, la fila tiene un id. como le digo que me cambie las imagenes de solo esa fila?

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar una variable bandera para verificar cuando está abierta la carpeta y cuando está cerrada, es como un switch que cuando se enciende muestra una imagen y oculta la otra y viceversa:

```js
$('.img-open').hide();
var bandera = true;
$('.card').on('click', function() {
    if (bandera){
      $('.img-open').show();
      $('.img-close').hide();
    }else{
      $('.img-close').show();
      $('.img-open').hide();
    }
    bandera = !bandera;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUR0Y.png" alt="" class="img-close">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv4z.png" alt="" class="img-open">
    <span>Gerencia</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Hay una funcion de Jquery para determinar si esta visible $('.img-close').is(":visible")

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.img-open').hide();
});

$('.card').on('click', function() {
    if($('.img-close').is(":visible")){
       $('.img-open').show();
       $('.img-close').hide();
      }else{
        $('.img-open').hide();
        $('.img-close').show();
      }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUR0Y.png" alt="" class="img-close">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv4z.png" alt="" class="img-open">
    <span>Gerencia</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacerlo con `toggleclass` agregando las imagenes al css

```js
$('.card').on('click', function() {
   $('#img').toggleClass("open-img close-img");
});
```

```css
.open-img{
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Rv4z.png');
   width:160px;
  height:130px;
}

.close-img{
 background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUR0Y.png');
  width:160px;
  height:130px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card">
    <div id="img" class="close-img"></div>
    <span>Gerencia</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias fue de demasiada útilidad